# What would happen to the reader if the main character dies in the story?

Tags: character-development

Can anyone tell me what would happen if the main character dies in the story?

Comment: Did you read books in which main character died? What happened to you?

Comment: What kind of effects are you looking for?  This is too open-ended as it stands now.  Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: "And nothing of value was lost."

Answer (score 2):

Death of the main character fits into different genres and serves its purpose in different ways there.

1. Tragedy (ex: [Romeo and Juliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_and_Juliet)). The protagonist(s) fail in their endeavor and die tragically. This is sad to the reader. But sometimes it is all right to be sad.
2. Make believe (ex: [Sleeping Beauty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_Beauty)). The protagonist appears to die, while later is revealed to be all right. A very strong dramatic effect, and hard one to execute without falling into cliches.
3. Story of a lifetime (ex: [Citizen Kane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane)). The story is really not about death, but about life. Readers accept main charater's death without many tears, even if he/she is very likable.
4. Not the real main character (ex: [Game of Thrones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_of_Thrones)). The character dies, but the story moves on. Can make some readers upset and make them stop reading.

Answer (score 0):

Other examples (in movies):

American Beauty:  The main character (also the narrator) dies. Actually the story is being narrated after he dies - we only see it at the end.

The Boys in Company C : (generally same as the above)

"Joy" : A main character (Joy's other) is narrator too. She dies 1/2-3/4 through the story but continues to narrate.  Interesting.

Star Wars: Obi Wan is killed (somewhat of a surprise) - but sort-of comes back a few times, in spirit, to mentor Luke Skywalker.

The Untouchables:  Malone - one of the main characters - brutally murdered. The younger "disciple/prodigee" (Elliot Ness) avenges Malone's death and carries on the legacy.  A VERY common theme.  (similar to Star Wars, above).

Pulp Fiction: Does this in a really interesting way. One of the main characters, actually the star of the film (Vincent Vega - played by John Travolta) dies halfway through the story - but because of the non-chronological way the story is told, se see several important acts of the movie, with him very much alive.

So, those are a few examples.